# Databinding a List inside of a data bound class to a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview, data-binding

still learning Databinding.. and I thought i got it down but i'm having trouble binding a List inside the class that's databinded.. if that makes any sense

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding _engine}
```

i would like that part of the code under the gridviewcolumn to just display the whole list of engines i have in that list... so ideally i'd like to maybe overwrite toString() or something to have it display something like.. for every engine in the list display the "_name" property.. but i have no idea how to do this?  i tried adding a method to the Engine class but i can't seem to access it through WPF.. kinda clueless here, would appreciate any help.

EDIT for clarification of what i want to do:

as of now my listview has 2 columns.. "Name" and "Active Engines".. the "Name" column is fine.. but under the "Active Engines".. since the listview is databound to PlayListCollection of a PlayList object...i would like to display everything listed under PlayList-->_engine-->_name. but since _engine is a list.. i would like to display all the "_name" properties in that list. let me know if that doesn't make sense still

```
<Window Name="This" ....>

<ListView x:Name="Playlists_ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding PlayListCollection, ElementName=This}" Background="#FFC9C9C9" Margin="0,5,0,0" Visibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" FontSize="12">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding _name}" Width="150"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Active Engines" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding _engine}" Width="240"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

public static ObservableCollection<Playlist> _PlayListCollection = new ObservableCollection<Playlist>();

public static ObservableCollection<Playlist> PlayListCollection
{
    get { return _PlayListCollection; }
}    

public class Playlist
{
    public string _name { get; set; }
    public List<Engine> _engine { get; set; }        

    public Playlist(string name, List<Engine> engine)
    {
        _name = name;
        _engine = engine;
    }        
}

public class Engine
{
    public string _name { get; set; }
    public string _ip { get; set; }
    public bool _active { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No sure I understand what you want to achieve. Do you want `ComboBox` when items come from `_engine` and selected value is `_name`?

Comment: as of now my listview has 2 columns.. "Name" and "Active Engines".. the "Name" column is fine.. but under the "Active Engines".. since the listview is databound to PlayListCollection of a PlayList object...i would like to display everything listed under PlayList-->_engine-->_name.  but since _engine is a list.. i would like to display all the "_name" properties in that list.  let me know if that doesn't make sense still

Comment: First of all, DisplayMemberPath without Binding only name of property. Let me know what is still wrong.

Comment: can you elaborate michael?  not sure i understand what you're trying to say

Comment: I meant  DisplayMemberBinding="_name" without binding.

Comment: i see, so just like dkozl mentioned below, hopefully that works!  (still learning databinding..) ty for this

Comment: Do not hesitate to ask if something is still not understandable.

Comment: @michael, I think you're confusing `DisplayMemberBinding` with `DisplayMemberPath`. [`DisplayMemberBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) is of a `BindingBase` type and as such requires binding

Comment: I was thinking about DisplayMemberPath but I wrote DisplayMemberBinding, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display `_name` of all `_engine` in one column then you can set `CellTemplate` to be `ItemsControl`. This should work:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Active Engines">
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding _engine}" DisplayMemberPath="_name">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         </ItemsControl>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

**EDIT**

To display items stacked horizontally you need to set `ItemsPanel` to horizontal `StackPanel`

Comment: gonna try this right now and get back to you and let u know how it goes, thanks

Comment: it worked!!!  thank you!  before i end this and give you credit, is there anyway to list the engine names horizontally instead of vertically?  rather not post a whole new question on SO just for that... if you don't see this no biggie.  will give you credit, ty!

Comment: check my updated answer. you need to change `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`

Comment: sigh dont think i'm ever going to understand databinding and wpf.... ty... gonna try right now

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. Basically if you want to show a list of something you need some sort of [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) and if you need to be able to select item from the list or need more advanced layout you go for one its descendants like `ListBox`, `ListView` or `DataGrid`

Comment: wrote that to my notes.  ty again